# How can I loop through every item of multiple list with special condition?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have 2 dataframes as below:

df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'feature1':['a1','a1','a1','b1','b1','b1'], 'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df1
```

df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'feature1':['c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2'], 'value2': [1,2,3,1,2,3]})
df2
```

My goal is to yield this result:

- Which a1 loops with c1 ; b1 loops with c2

```
| feature1 | value | feature2 | value2|
| -------- | ----- | -------- | ----- |
| a1       | 1     | c1       | 1     |
| a1       | 1     | c1       | 2     |
| a1       | 1     | c1       | 3     |
| a1       | 2     | c1       | 1     |
| a1       | 2     | c1       | 2     |
| a1       | 2     | c1       | 3     |
| a1       | 3     | c1       | 1     |
| a1       | 3     | c1       | 2     |
| a1       | 3     | c1       | 3     |
| b1       | 4     | c2       | 1     |
| b1       | 4     | c2       | 2     |
| b1       | 4     | c2       | 3     |
| b1       | 5     | c2       | 1     |
| b1       | 5     | c2       | 2     |
| b1       | 5     | c2       | 3     |
| b1       | 6     | c2       | 1     |
| b1       | 6     | c2       | 2     |
| b1       | 6     | c2       | 3     |
```

What I have done is as below:

1. Convert the value & value2 into 2 lists:

```
list1 = df1[df1.columns[1]].values.tolist()
list1

output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

```
list2 = df2[df2.columns[1]].values.tolist()
list2

output: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

2. Do a multiloop iteration using list comprehension:

```
lim1, lim2 = [], []

for x, y in [(x,y) for x in list1 for y in list2]:
    #print(x, y, z)

    lim1.append(x)
    lim2.append(y)

    df_limit = pd.DataFrame({
        "value": lim1, 
        "value2": lim2,
    })
```

The result loops entire columns instead of what I need:

```
value   value2
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   1
4   1   2
5   1   3
6   2   1
7   2   2
8   2   3
9   2   1
10  2   2
11  2   3
12  3   1
13  3   2
14  3   3
15  3   1
16  3   2
17  3   3
18  4   1
19  4   2
20  4   3
21  4   1
22  4   2
23  4   3
24  5   1
25  5   2
26  5   3
27  5   1
28  5   2
29  5   3
30  6   1
31  6   2
32  6   3
33  6   1
34  6   2
35  6   3
```

I am trying to figure out if use df.groupby() for the features and do list comprehension would help but so far I am unable to proceed...

The real life example is much more complicated than this as there more than 100 of combinations, so would to seek a more iterable way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Loops are basically *never* the answer when it comes to pandas.

Filtering after cross joining everything:

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['a1','a1','a1','b1','b1','b1'], 'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'feature':['c1','c1','c1','c2','c2','c2'], 'value': [1,2,3,1,2,3]})
df = df1.merge(df2, 'cross', suffixes=['1', '2'])
out = df[df.feature1.eq('a1') & df.feature2.eq('c1') | df.feature1.eq('b1') & df.feature2.eq('c2')].reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   feature1  value1 feature2  value2
0        a1       1       c1       1
1        a1       1       c1       2
2        a1       1       c1       3
3        a1       2       c1       1
4        a1       2       c1       2
5        a1       2       c1       3
6        a1       3       c1       1
7        a1       3       c1       2
8        a1       3       c1       3
9        b1       4       c2       1
10       b1       4       c2       2
11       b1       4       c2       3
12       b1       5       c2       1
13       b1       5       c2       2
14       b1       5       c2       3
15       b1       6       c2       1
16       b1       6       c2       2
17       b1       6       c2       3
```

---

Filtering before cross joining:

```
a1_c1 = [df1[df1.feature.eq('a1')], df2[df2.feature.eq('c1')]]
b1_c2 = [df1[df1.feature.eq('b1')], df2[df2.feature.eq('c2')]]
dfs = []
for pair in [a1_c1, b1_c2]:
    temp_df = pd.merge(*pair, how='cross', suffixes=['1','2'])
    dfs.append(temp_df)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   feature1  value1 feature2  value2
0        a1       1       c1       1
1        a1       1       c1       2
2        a1       1       c1       3
3        a1       2       c1       1
4        a1       2       c1       2
5        a1       2       c1       3
6        a1       3       c1       1
7        a1       3       c1       2
8        a1       3       c1       3
9        b1       4       c2       1
10       b1       4       c2       2
11       b1       4       c2       3
12       b1       5       c2       1
13       b1       5       c2       2
14       b1       5       c2       3
15       b1       6       c2       1
16       b1       6       c2       2
17       b1       6       c2       3
```